# How do I get inside the caged area in the Temple Ruins near the South entrance?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

I have been exploring the Temple for what seems like an age and I can't find my way in to this area. Can anyone tell me where I need to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, you need to kill an Earth Eater to get into the room.  If you're not strong enough yet, complete some more Main/Sidequests until you are.

Teleport to the Cactuar in Golden Chamber: Lower Level.  Take the door to the south and you'll see the Earth Eater.  Killing it allows you into the tunnel behind it.  Follow the Path of Brimstone to the end and you'll be in Scorched Earth: Lower Level.  Run through the southeast door.  This leads you to one of those red seals, and this one unlocks the door back in the main room.  Right next to it is a ladder.  Climb this ladder to get into the cage.